# Adding button gradient before appearing in iOS

Tags: ios, button, gradient

I want to use gradient for a button in iOS, but since the button's frame (button.layer.bounds) changes because of Auto Layout, I found that I have to put the insertSublayer in the viewDidAppear method -- which means the button first appears without the gradient and then gets repainted with it.  Is there anyway to get the final button size in viewWillAppear so that I can apply the correct size gradient before it appears?

Here's how I do it now:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    CAGradientLayer *gradient1=[CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradient1.colors=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)light.CGColor,(id)dark.CGColor,nil];
    gradient1.cornerRadius=10;
    gradient1.frame=_go_button.layer.bounds;
    gradient1.borderColor=dark.CGColor;
    gradient1.borderWidth=1;
    [_go_button.layer insertSublayer:gradient1 atIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes by asking a question leads you to finding your own answer....  Here's a link to a website I found that answered it:  [has the solution](https://marcosantadev.com/calayer-auto-layout-swift)

The simple answer is to put the gradient code into viewDidLayoutSubviews instead of viewDidAppear.

Comment: You should just create the gradient layer once and update the frame in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. At the moment your code will add another new layer every time that function is called.

Comment: Right you are.   I did a conditional check that only ran the code the first time viewDidLayoutSubviews is called, but your approach of doing everything but the .frame assignment early is more elegant.